# UpdateProgress only working first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, progress-bar

I am using an UpdateProgress control that should be visible after clicking my search button, writing on screen "processing...". It is only visible for the 1st time when I do the search, all searches after the 1st won't trigger the UpdateProgress as supposed.

Could someone point me what is the problem?

Here is my aspx code.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="myButton">
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox"/>
   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="myButton" onClick="myButton_Click" type="submit"></asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="myButton" /></Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                ...
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
<ProgressTemplate>
   Processing...
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: Don't know if this will help the problem, but you can remove `type="submit"` from the LinkButton because LinkButtons *are* submit buttons. And, fyi, a LinkButton cannot be a DefaultButton. Just in case, make the 'O' a capital letter in OnClick.

Comment: yes, thats trash code, but its not causing this problem

Comment: Figured you would have gotten an error when the page loaded if it was a problem. Sometimes can't tell when inserting html attr's.

Comment: The OnClick is calling the code behind? It's causing a postback every time?

Comment: @wazz the onClick will perform a query on code behind, and it works fine every time I do a search

Comment: I just copied your code and the only problem was that there is no button called `ButtonPesquisa`. It looks like there's something going on we can't see in your post.

Comment: @wazz I just forgot to update "ButtonPesquisa" ID here in my post, it should be "myButton". In CS code its making a SQL connection and running a query.  I have tested again code and I can now make it work with success. I  am not sure what happened, probably some mistake I have made. I want to thank you for your help!